# setTimeout not fully cancelled before component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Why am I still getting an error about setting state in an unmounted component? In the error trace it points to the `setTimeout` in `foo()`.  I clear my async timer and also add a check before I perform my api call - I don't see where this warning is coming from.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({alive: true});
    this.foo();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({alive: false, timer: 0});
}

foo() {

    if (!this.state.alive) return;
    fetch('/api/etc/', {method: 'GET', headers: {'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {

    if (!json.length) return;

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        timer: setTimeout(this.foo.bind(this), 500)
    });
    });
}
```

Comment: You never clear the timer anywhere. Don't call `setState` in `componentWillUnmount`, just call `clearTimeout` if necessary.

Comment: this works, thanks. whatever i was reading said to set timer to 0.

Answer (score 7):

### *** Updated Answer & also Function Component version with React Hooks ***

As Evan Trimboli pointed out in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51725763/settimeout-not-fully-cancelled-before-component-unmounts/51726008?noredirect=1#comment90436036_51726008) below, there is no need to store the timeout ID in the state as `it doesn't impact rendering`.

So store the `timeout` ID in the class instance and use it to clear timeout in `componentWillUnmount`.

*Run the code below to see it in action*

#### Class Component version (prior to, not including v16.8.0)

```js
    class TodoApp extends React.Component {
     timeout = 0;
    
      hello = () => console.log("hello world!")
      
      componentDidMount() {
       this.timeout = setTimeout(this.hello, 500);
      }
      
      componentWillUnmount() {
       clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      }
      
      render() {
        return (
          <div>demo</div>
        )
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app"></div>
```

#### Function Component version with a Hook (possible since v16.8.0)

[React.useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) let's you put a setup & teardown logic in a same block.

```js
const TodoApp = () => {
  const hello = () => console.log("hello world!")

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(hello, 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  });
  
  return (
    <div>demo</div>
  )
}

    ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app"></div>
```

---

### Old Answer (using State to store timeout ID).

Store the timeout ID in the state, and use that to clear out the timeout in `componentWillUnmount`.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     timeout: null
    }
    
    this.hello = this.hello.bind(this);
  }
  
  hello() { console.log("hello world!"); }
  
  componentDidMount() {
   const timeout = setTimeout(this.hello, 500);
   this.setState({timeout});
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
   clearTimeout(this.state.timeout);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>demo</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It's probably better to store the timer on the class instance, since it won't impact rendering.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You are absolutely right. I've updated the answer according to your suggestion. Thanks Evan 